# How to check if an argument is passed to bash script

Tags: bash

I am new to scripting.

My code is

```
#!/bin/bash
path=$1
if [ condition ]; then
.......
fi
```

**How do i check if the argument is passed while calling the script**?(What should i write as condition inside if statement)

Comment: `()` is not part of the bash `if` syntax for the record. Have you tried looking at any bash scripting tutorials? This should be fairly easy to find in just about all of them.

Comment: sorry that was a mistake, c programming hangover

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423306/how-do-i-find-the-number-of-arguments-passed-to-a-bash-script

Comment: Have a look at: [Introduction to if](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finally found the answer with the help of all

```
if(($#==1));#check if number of arguments is 1 and return a boolean value
then
<code>
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

[The syntax of a bash `if`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) statement is:

```
if statement; ... then statement; ... else statement; ... fi
```

The statements following `then` are executed if the last statement before `then` succeeded; otherwise the statements following `else` (if it is present; `else` is optional.)

The [number of arguments passed](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) to a function is `$#`.

You can do arithmetic comparisons with a [conditional statement](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-select), whose syntax is `(( arithmetic expression ))`. (The bash manual doesn't have a precise index tag for `(( ))`; it's just underneath the provided link, which is for the `select` statement.)